# [OpenCV Videocapture]Why isn't ret reading?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

The code shows correct image, but show error message after image 'frame' playback. so I couldn't get 'res' image
It just shows me 'No Object Files' error message.
Which part should I fix to make it work?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('ObjectTrack.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if not ret:
        print("No Object Files")
        break
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_orange = np.array([100,200,200])
    upper_orange = np.array([140,255,255])

    mask_orange = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_orange, upper_orange)

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask_orange)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind your error is that the frame is None(Null). and your code enters into this `if`

```
if not ret:
    print("No Object Files")
    break
```

and then gets out of the `while` loop ( `while cap.isOpened(): ...` ).

Just change the indentation and also the `if` condition

**like this:**

```
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret: # if frame is not None:

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        lower_orange = np.array([100, 200, 200])
        upper_orange = np.array([140, 255, 255])

        mask_orange = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_orange, upper_orange)

        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask_orange)

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('res', res)

        if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The reason is further discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64052803/14119218).